# how do I enable JPEG support with PIL?

Tags: python, image

By default, PIL doesn't have jpeg support on the Raspberry Pi, so it returns the following:

```
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

This can also be seen while installing PIL:

```
*** JPEG support not available
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR: uninstall PIL, install and link libjpeg-dev, and reinstall PIL.**

The general solution is to [install libjpeg-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632261/pil-jpeg-library-help) before installing PIL:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev
```

However, PIL still doesn't know where to find the shared library. Following the general solution (above) doesn't work since the Pi is ARM-based, not intel32/64. Still, it isn't hard to find the library and link it:

```
find /usr/lib -name libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
```

reinstalling PIL works properly now:

```
sudo pip install PIL
...
--- JPEG support available
```

hoorays!

Comment: When running /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so, I get a premission denied error. However, when I try to use sudo /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so, it says command is not found. How can I fix this?

Comment: The .so is a library, not an executable, @human

Comment: Thanks. For reference, this also resolves the mirror issue with Pillow/Python3

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to install PIL (actually, the Pillow fork) via,

```
sudo apt-get install python-imaging
```

as recommended [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753781/1224002).  This will also install the dependencies required for JPEG support.