# How to make IO Error: Decoder jpeg go away?

Tags: python

I found a solution [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9361/how-do-i-enable-jpeg-support-with-pil/) but it seems to only work with python 2.7 and I need it for python 3.2. Also how do I uninstall a library?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the solution. I ran this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg8-dev    
find /usr/lib -name libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo pip-3.2 install PIL
```